# How to make app icon appear in client's mobile apps on download

Tags: android, jquery, ios, iphone

I didn't really know how best to phrase this question, so I apologize for any confusion!

I am a web-based developer who has never tried to make a mobile app before. A client of mine I have been working with for the last year requested a mobile app to accompany their website.

Instead of creating a full mobile app, my client suggested having a basic mobile website accompanied by an app-like icon that displays in their mobile apps when they download the file. Clicking on the icon would open a browser-based mobile website.

Basically, I'm trying to figure out how to make a custom app icon automatically appear in a client's mobile apps when they download a file. Clicking on the mobile app will open a browser-based website.

Any ideas? Am I going about this the wrong way? Any help is appreciated. :)

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Have you seen Android docs? apple store doesn't allow such app because its only website.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your describing the "[apple-touch-icon](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons)".  When a user creates a bookmark, and add it's to their home screen, and "App" like icon will display. Touching this icon will open the browser.

You could also wrap your HTML 5 mobile site in a native "wrapper" like [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/).